# rabbitmq token based authentication

Tags: django, push-notification, rabbitmq

I'm planning on using rabbitmq to achieve push notification in my web app.

Each user will have a queue. I want to prevent unauthorised users from subscribing to other people's queues. Can this be achieved using an auth token that a user must provide?

As a workaround currently I'm thinking about django proxying rabbimq in order to check if the provided auth token is correct, and only pass on request to rabbitmq if authenticated...but this feels less than optimal!

Comment: Why to you think it's not optimal? Do you provide direct access to RabbitMQ to unauthorized users? Does authorized users access RabbitMQ directly? If so, do they share same credentials?

Comment: I think this is sub-optimal because rabbitmq is on a different server to django, so proxying will be another round trip and so increase latency. Higher latency is not a massive drawback though. It also means the notifications stop working if django is not up.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same functionality by using `exclusive` queue and RabbitMQ permission.

> Exclusive queues may only be accessed by the current connection, and
>   are deleted when that connection closes. Passive declaration of an
>   exclusive queue by other connections are not allowed.

Comment: that would be nice, except notifications will be pushed to the queue. We don't want the user to miss notifications if they were not logged in at the time they occurred.

Comment: In this case take a look at `dead-letter-exchange` you may route messages that are not endded up in the queue to a "default" queue. Or you can use publish confirms with "mandatory" flag. This way publisher will know if message wasn't delivered to the queue.

Comment: Maybe it's good idea just to handle auth on application side and do not mix application logic with message broker logic?

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like `exclusive` queues won't allow my django app from adding messages to the queue - it looks like only the connection that creates the queue can interact with it.

Comment: When you publish message, you not publishing it to the queue, you publish it to the exchange, so I don't see any issues with that